# How do I fix error "Kernel panic – not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block" and "LZMA data is corrupt"

Tags: linux, boot, kernel-panic

I recently bought a new computer and I am experiencing problems while *trying* to install Linux.

Things I have tried:

A variety of distributions:

- Ubuntu;
- Elementary OS;
- Crunchbang++;
- Manjaro; and
- Antergos

Every time I try to boot the system either locks and nothing happens or it returns me the same error:

> Kernel panic – not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

I have also tried both booting using an USB flash drive and using CD/DVD. And I have tried booting using Legacy and UEFI.

In the last days I have been to a variety of websites and articles, mainly:

- http://itslaves.com/web/guest/forum/message_boards/message/66813
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0

I have also searched the StackExchange network but with no success.

The problem with the purposed solutions is:

a) They are for people who already have Linux in their machines and have corrupted their file-systems;

b) For one to execute the presented solutions a Live CD is needed and I can't even boot Linux so this becomes impossible for me.

My motherboard is Gigabyte B85M-D3PH and my processor is an i5-4460, in case this information helps in any way.

Posting here is my last resort.

Comment: Does the problem occur when trying to boot from install media, or after install when you try to get into a new system?

Comment: It happens when I try to boot. Sorry for the delay.